# What are some reasons Bayesian Optimization might not work for a CNN

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, hyperparameters, hyperopt

I tried to apply Bayesian Optimisation to a simple CNN for the MNIST handwritten digits dataset and I'm getting little indication that it works. I've tried doing k-fold validation to smooth out noise but still doesn't seem like the optimisation is making any headway in converging towards optimal parameters. In general, what are some of the main reasons Bayesian Optimization might fail? And in my particular case?

The rest of this is just context and code snippets.

**Model definition:**

```
def define_model(learning_rate, momentum):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    opt = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

**One training run** with hyperparameters: batch_size = 32, learning rate = 1e-2, momentum = 0.9, 10 epochs. (blue = training, yellow = validation).

[image]

**Box and whisker plot for accuracy in 5-fold cross validation**, with the same hyperparameters as above (to get a sense of the spread)

[image]

**Grid search** holding batch_size at 32, and keeping with 10 epoch. I did this on single evaluations rather than 5-fold as the spread wasn't large enough to spoil the results.

[image]
[image]

**Bayesian optimization**. As above, batch_size=32 and 10 epoch. Searching over the same ranges. But this time with 5-fold cross-validation to smooth out noise. It's supposed to go out to 100 iterations but that's still another 20 hours away.

```
space = {'lr': hp.loguniform('lr', np.log(np.sqrt(10)*1e-4), np.log(1e-1)), 'momentum': 1 - hp.loguniform('momentum', np.log(np.sqrt(10)*1e-3), np.log(np.sqrt(10)*1e-1))}
tpe_best = fmin(fn=objective, space=space, algo=tpe.suggest, trials=Trials(), max_evals=100)
```

[image]

The trialled learning rates
[image]

The trialled momentums
[image]

It looked nice from about iteration 27 to 49 but then it lost its mind again.

**EDIT**

More detail for those who asked.

Imports

```
# basic utility libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
import pickle
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

# keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Input, BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.models import load_model

# learning and optimisation helper libraries
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, Trials, hp, rand
from hyperopt.pyll.stochastic import sample
```

Single evaluation

```
def evaluate_model(trainX, trainY, testX, testY, max_epochs, learning_rate, momentum, batch_size, model=None, callbacks=[]):
    if model == None:
        model = define_model(learning_rate, momentum)
    history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=max_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=0, callbacks = callbacks)
    return model, history
```

Cross validation

```
def evaluate_model_cross_validation(trainX, trainY, max_epochs, learning_rate, momentum, batch_size, n_folds=5):
    scores, histories = list(), list()
    # prepare cross validation
    kfold = KFold(n_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
    # enumerate splits
    for trainFold_ix, testFold_ix in kfold.split(trainX):
        # select rows for train and test
        trainFoldsX, trainFoldsY, testFoldX, testFoldY = trainX[trainFold_ix], trainY[trainFold_ix], trainX[testFold_ix], trainY[testFold_ix]
        # fit model
        model = define_model(learning_rate, momentum)
        history = model.fit(trainFoldsX, trainFoldsY, epochs=max_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(testFoldX, testFoldY), verbose=0)
        # evaluate model
        _, acc = model.evaluate(testFoldX, testFoldY, verbose=0)
        # stores scores
        scores.append(acc)
        histories.append(history)
    return scores, histories
```

How I set things up for Bayesian Optimisation (or random search)

```
def selective_search(kind, space, max_evals, batch_size=32):

    trainX, trainY, testX, testY = prep_data()

    histories = list()
    hyperparameter_sets = list()
    scores = list()

    def objective(params):
        lr, momentum = params['lr'], params['momentum']
        accuracies, _ = evaluate_model_cross_validation(trainX, trainY, max_epochs=10, learning_rate=lr, momentum=momentum, batch_size=batch_size, n_folds=5)
        score = np.log10(1 - np.mean(accuracies))
        scores.append(score)
        with open('{}_scores.pickle'.format(kind), 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(scores, file)
        hyperparameter_sets.append({'learning_rate': lr, 'momentum': momentum, 'batch_size': batch_size})
        with open('{}_hpsets.pickle'.format(kind), 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(hyperparameter_sets, file)
        return score

    if kind == 'bayesian':
        tpe_best = fmin(fn=objective, space=space, algo=tpe.suggest, trials=Trials(), max_evals=max_evals)
    elif kind == 'random':
        tpe_best = fmin(fn=objective, space=space, algo=rand.suggest, trials=Trials(), max_evals=max_evals)
    else:
        raise BaseError('First parameter "kind" must be either "bayesian" or "random"')

    return histories, hyperparameter_sets, scores
```

Then how I actually run the Bayesian optimization.

```
space = {'lr': hp.loguniform('lr', np.log(np.sqrt(10)*1e-4), np.log(1e-1)), 'momentum': 1 - hp.loguniform('momentum', np.log(np.sqrt(10)*1e-3), np.log(np.sqrt(10)*1e-1))}

histories, hyperparameter_sets, scores = selective_search(kind='bayesian', space=space, max_evals=100, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: Hi, could you upload the full code for the Bayesian optmization step and a source for your ConvNN?

Comment: @AlexNe I've just tacked it onto the end. Hope it's enough. Can also share a notebook over private chat if it's easier. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: Hi again, while I test this, here is a good theoretical summary of bayesian inference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.02063.pdf . On page 6, they define the problem. They also give an in-depth overview over failure modes from p.6 to p.21.

Comment: @AlexNe See an update below

Answer (score 2):

This is an update on my progress, and somewhat answers my question. The headline is that I wasn't running enough iterations.

1. **Score over iterations** and 2. **Running best score over iterations**

   - We do observe a trend towards better accuracy as seen by the fitted line. This is probably less because the minimum is improving, and more because the algorithm spends less time evaluating hyperparameters which are clearly not candidates for optimal performance.
2. **Learning rate over iterations** and 4. **the corresponding box and whisker plots**

   - A strange thing we see here is convergence and divergence of the trialled hyperparameters. My guess is because the noise from the statistical deviations are not allowing the algorithm to map out the terrain reliably. It can't settle on a minimum because each time it tests a certain set of hyperparameters it gets a slightly different answer.
   - Nevertheless we do see hints that the algorithm restricts its search space to a narrower neighborhood than the full range, as expected.
3. **Momentum over iterations** and 6. **the corresponding box and whisker plots**

   - Here we make similar observations to the learning rates. What's interesting, is the way the average tends to converge and diverge with the learning rate. Remember I mentioned earlier that as momentum increases, we need to decrease learning rate to maintain good model training performance. So there is somehow a coupling between momentum and learning rate if we try to maintain good performance. This is what the optimisation algorithm is demonstrating for us here!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @ Alexander Soare Your optimization looks good. When doing MCMC these jagged trajectories in plot 3 and 5 are a sign of a multimodal posterior distribution, i.e. there are multiple local Minima in the Objective and the algorithm is exploring them well. Good Job!

Comment: Also regarding your aim of finding a definitive answer, Bayesian optimization by design estimates uncertainty. You could use the maximum of your posterior density, although the mathematically correct way would be to just draw another sample from your distribution every time you retrain and use those parameters.